# Como fazer a tela rolar ao clicar em uma tag <a>

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5

Na página de um produto existem dois links: 1 com a quantidade de comentários que já existem para o produto e outro dizendo "Escreva um comentário".
Mais para baixo na página existe uma "aba" tab com a parte de comentários.
Quando você clica no link ele aciona a aba dos comentários, mas não desliza a tela até lá então parece que o link nem faz nada.
O que é preciso fazer para que esse link tenha essas duas funções ao mesmo tempo?

Obs.: Já tentei simplesmente colocar #tab-review no href NÃO FUNCIONA

Código dos Links:

```
<a href="" onclick="$('a[href=\'#tab-review\']').trigger('click'); return false;"><?php echo $reviews; ?></a> / <a href="" onclick="$('a[href=\'#tab-review\']').trigger('click'); return false;"><?php echo $text_write; ?></a></p>
```

Link da página:
https://www.lupmed.com.br/bandagem-dynamic-tape-preto-5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente criar uma função no clique e chamar todas ações dentro dela, exemplo:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="scrollToComentarios()">Escreva um comentário</a>

<script>
function scrollToComentarios() {
    if ($('.product-tabs').length != 0) {
        $('a[href=\'#tab-review\']').trigger('click');
        $('#input-name').focus();  // adiciona foco ao primeiro input do form de comentarios
        $("html, body").animate({
            scrollTop: $('.product-tabs').offset().top
        }, 1000);
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Funcionou Exatamente como eu precisava. Muito obrigado!

Comment: Tem como já deixar o input "acionado" também? Para o usuário não precisar clicar

Comment: Tem sim, editei a resposta com esse novo elemento

Answer (score 1):

Coloca a ID #tad-review na referência do seu link.

Ex:

```html
<a href="#tab-review" onclick="$('a[href=\'#tab-review\']').trigger('click'); return false;"><?php echo $reviews; ?></a> / <a href="" onclick="$('a[href=\'#tab-review\']').trigger('click'); return false;"><?php echo $text_write; ?></a></p>
```

Comment: Não funciona :(

Comment: Então pode ser que o onclick esteja prevenindo a href... tenta colocar pelo seu jQuery no onclick: window.location.href='#tab-review';

Comment: Não funcionou :(

Comment: Caraca bixo, uma terceira alternativa que eu vejo é usar o scrollTop no seu onlick... $('html, body').scrollTop(0); Ai troca o '0' pela quantidade de pixel que vc deseja descer.

Comment: como faz isso exatamente?

Comment: Vou adicionar uma nova resposta aqui, peraí.

Answer (score 0):

Ola.
é só você colocar assim

```
<a href = '#Exemplo'>Vá para o paragrafo sobre JS</a>
<p id ="Exemplo" name="Exemplo">JS Java Script</p>
```

é só colocar no link a mesma coisa que você colocou no nome e no id do parágrafo que vc deseja redirecionar o usuario

Segue um link caso ainda tenha dúvidas
http://www.otimizacao-sites-busca.com/links/links-navegacao-mesma-pagina.htm

Comment: Não, não funciona. Já tentei isso

Comment: aparece algum erro ou simplesmente não redireciona?

Comment: Não aparece erro

Comment: Se você tiver usando Bootstrap dá pra fazer isso , colocar isso no paragrafo a ser direcionado

Colocar o titulo do paragrafo como um link com esses atributos , ou criar um link ao lado do titulo com um icone talvez , para o usuario ser direcionado para o link ao lado do titulo

<a class="anchorjs-link " href="#css" aria-label="Anchor" data-anchorjs-icon="#" ></a>

Comment: Se isso não ajudar tenta tirar o script do seu link e só deixar o link html msm

Comment: Tem como criar uma resposta com isso? Não entendi  muito bem como fazer

Comment: se tirar o Script ele não faz o que eu preciso cara

Answer (score 0):

Colega, como as outras alternativas não deram certo, você pode usar o ScrollTop junto no seu onclick.
Oo códico é:

```
$('html, body').scrollTop(0);
```

Suponha que o local que vc deseja descer está à 1200px do topo, aí coloca essa quantidade no lugar do zero:

```
$('html, body').scrollTop(1200);
```

No seu código, ficaria assim:

```
<a href="#tab-review" onclick="$('html, body').scrollTop(**1200**); $('a[href=\'#tab-review\']').trigger('click'); return false;"><?php echo $reviews; ?></a> / <a href="" onclick="$('a[href=\'#tab-review\']').trigger('click'); return false;"><?php echo $text_write; ?></a></p
```

Comment: E como que eu faço o responsivo disso? Tem como?

Comment: Dá sim, é melhor vc chamar uma função e colocar as condições dentro dela... Ex: se for desktop > descer até 1200px, se for mobile > descer até 1700px